# How can I shut Bradford up?

Tags: xcom-2

He's starting to get on my nerves with all of the talk he produces during missions, ESPECIALLY during civilian rescue missions.    He always says the same few lines over and over and over and I'd like to get his voice out of my head.

He says things all the time like:

- "We're losing civilians left and right Commander, we need to STOP THIS"
- "We're seeing heavy casualties Commander, we have to STOP THIS"

How can I reduce the amount of times he gets on the voice comms to nag me about how many HEAVY CASUALITIES I have been undergoing? This seems to be the status quo on just about every civilian rescue mission, even if only a few hostages have died so far.

Comment: I can't test it as I don't have xcom2, but [the quiet bradford mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=621358553) seems to do what you want.

Comment: Question title is kinda spoilerish....

Comment: Bradford's dialogue during retaliation missions is THE WORST, it's so incredibly annoying! I'm like, "I'm fending off a Berserker, 2 Mutons, 3 Advent troopers, and a Faceless to boot, *simultaneously*, how about you get your butt down here and try doing better than me!"

Comment: He only did this to me on the *first* retaliation mission? After that he just left me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GodEmperorDune stated, the mod [Quiet Bradford](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=621358553) will shut him up, but only on retaliation missions.

The [maker of the mod has stated on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/459cgv/even_the_source_code_thinks_bradford_is_naggy/czw7wpc) he will later add functionality to shut him up in other non-retaliation missions.